# How to read all binary from a HttpRequest, in Dart?

Tags: stream, binary, request, dart

`HttpRequest` in Dart, is a `Stream<List<int>>`, how to get the binary content as `List<int>`?

I tried:

```
request.toList().then((data) {
    // but data is a List<List<int>> !!!
});
```

It seems I should not use `toList`. What's the correct method I should use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do it is to set the `onDone` callback for `listen()`. The callback is fired when it has completed. Then just create a list of integers and add to it per every event:

```dart
List<int> data = [];
request.listen(data.addAll, onDone: () {
  // `data` has here the entire contents.
});
```

Alternatively, here's a one-liner:

```dart
request.reduce((p, e) => p..addAll(e)).then((data) {
  // `data` has here the entire contents.  
});
```

I'll also add Anders Johnsen's great tip of using `BytesBuilder` class, which I think you should prefer:

```dart
 request.fold(new BytesBuilder(), (b, d) => b..add(d)).then((builder) {
   var data = builder.takeBytes();
 });
```

Answer (score 9):

We recently added a `BytesBuilder` available in `dart:io`. See [here](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_io/BytesBuilder.html) for more info.

In your case the code could look like this:

```
request.fold(new BytesBuilder(), (builder, data) => builder..add(data))
    .then((builder) {
      var data = builder.takeBytes();
      // use data.
    });
```

The cool thing about using `BytesBuilder` is that it's optimized for large chunks of binary data. Note that I'm using `takeBytes` to get the internal buffer of the `BytesBuilder`, avoiding an extra copy.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `dart:html`, you can use

```
HttpRequest.request('/blub.bin', responseType: 'arraybuffer').then((request) {
```

to get the response as one array buffer. You can access the buffer via `request.response`. But to access the bytes, you need to create a `Uint8List` represenation of the data:

```
List<int> bytes = new Uint8List.view(request.response);
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to get the content of `request` from the server side. I use AJAX to post a file to the server, and I want to get the content.

Comment: That isn't clear at all after reading your question, how about updating it?